# Microsoft Graph API - Customer specific Unique Identifier for users in Azure AD

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to consume Microsoft Graph API to provision/de-provision users and groups to/from Azure Active Directory.  I want to be able to add users to Azure active directory(AD) from **any local database or HR system** not just from local AD. Each of these local databases have thier own unique identifiers for the users. I need to store these unique identifiers also in the Azure AD when I  create the users in Azure AD.

In the documentation(https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user) , it is mentioned that **onPremisesImmutableId** can be used for this purpose only  if you are using a federated domain for the user’s userPrincipalName (UPN) property.

**My question is:** What to do for user identities in local database where federated domain is  not relevant? Can I use **onPremisesImmutableId** property for storing these unique identifiers in Azure AD. If so, will I be able to do CRUD operations on User object using onPremisesImmutableId property?

Please guide me on this..
Thanks so much...

Comment: Have you just tried creating a user through the Microsoft Graph API? In Azure AD Graph API this property documentation says that it is required if the user is federated. But that doesn't mean you can't specify it for other users. So why not just try it with [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)?

Comment: Hi Juunas, thanks for the quick response. I want to map a unique, immutable, mandatory field in Azure to "unique identifier" in my localDB.  In Azure, it is not a mandatory field for non-federated users, so users can be created without a value for it. I am concerned about the scenario where user is created directly in Azure AD without a value for onPremisesImmutableId and read into local db. How to link these two users? While reading user into localDb, shall I create a unique identifier in localDb and update the same into Azure. It will be a multi step process. Please guide me.